# Redirecting url with cdn in htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

from

```
cdn1.example.com
cdn2.example.com
cdn3.example.com
```

to

```
example.com
```

Please let me know how to redirect those?....

Answer (score 0):

You could have provided more details and also what you have tried, anyways here you go:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(cdn1|cdn2|cdn3)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As a *bonus*, any eventual path and/or querystring is preserved, I guess you would need that.

**EDIT :** As you requested, here is a *cdnx* version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn[0-9]+\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's a very simple regex, you can easily tweak it, anyways, I've updated my answer.